# When was the Midrash Tanhuma written?

Tags: history, midrash, provenance

[This article](http://mida.org.il/2017/12/08/%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%AA-%D7%95%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%91-%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A3-%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9F-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%A9-%D7%9C%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%9F/) (Hebrew) claims that the Midrash Tanhuma was likely written after the Quran. A response in the talkbacks says that this is incorrect. Neither provide any source.

Does anyone know what the actual consensus of this is? When was the Midrash Tanhuma written?

Comment: If you are asking what traditional religious authorities have opined on the topic, see this question: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/59526/8775. If you want the view of historians in general on the different editions of Tanhum and their dates of redaction, check out Wikipedia's [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanhuma). || Note that whether you mean the consensus of religious authorities or the consensus of historians, there isn't necessarily one.

Comment: @mevaqesh Why isn't that a duplicate

Comment: @DoubleAA That question is limited to traditional sources. This one might include the views of critical historians, and might even be limited to that (pending clarification).

Comment: @mevaqesh Mimah nafshach - if it’s looking for traditional sources, then it’s a dupe, and if it’s looking for secular sources, it should be off-topic.

Comment: @donielf that is incorrect as I believe i have pointed out to you on numerous occasions. Asking who wrote a classical Jewish text is on topic since it is about a Jewish text. That the question accommodates answers in which the evidence gathered about a classical Jewish text hardly renders it off topic.

Comment: @mevaqesh We have indeed had this discussion before, and I finally have been able to track down the [relevant meta post](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1573/9682). Perhaps we should take this discussion over there.

Answer (score 3):

Midrash Yelammedenu, the precursor to Midrash Tanhuma, was composed c. 400-600 CE. During the seventh to eighth centuries, it is possible that "possible that numerous segments of the Tanhuma-type midrash have already received their final form". However, it is likely that the final version of Tanhuma was completed around 700-900 CE (Lerner, The Works of *Aggadic Midrash and the Esther Midrashim* in "The Literature of the Sages," pp. 149-152).